# Is there a way I can download the headers only as a file in Django ImportExportModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

Is there a way to just download a file that contains only the field titles?

[image]

For example, the download template button will download a file that has all the necessary fields as shown in the help text.

The downloaded file would look like this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.  You need to [declare a resource](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/e83da278ff22aaa9ff0cfb138a7fb830c8392e61/tests/core/admin.py#L14) and override the `export()` method so that it creates a new Dataset containing only headers.

```py
class BookResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def export(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().export(queryset, args, kwargs)
        return tablib.Dataset(headers=data.headers)
```

Comment: hi it's you again. Thanks for the help on the previous problem, now I'm back here. This works but I need to attach the function to another trigger button and not the actual export button.

Comment: I would suggest to get as far as you can, and if you are stuck please create a new question.

Comment: New qustion like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012261/custom-export-url-for-export-headers-function).