# Custom Export URL for export headers function

Tags: html, django, django-import-export

I have this in my resources:

```
def export(self, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
    data = super().export(queryset, args, kwargs)
    return tablib.Dataset(headers=data.headers)
```

It exports only the header fields for files. I want to bind it to a button only:

but considering the custom export is inside my model resource, it is also applied to the export button.

[image]

This is my custom template:

How do I add it only to the template button? Something like a new URL?

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block object-tools %}

{{ baseURL | json_script:"base-url" }}
{{ templateType | json_script:"template-type" }}

<ul class="object-tools">
    <li><a href="/crowdfunding/investment/export/?">Template</a></li>
    <li><a href="/crowdfunding/investment/import/" class="import_link">Import</a></li>
    <li><a href="/crowdfunding/investment/export/?" class="export_link">Export</a></li>
    <li><a href="/crowdfunding/investment/add/" class="addlink">Add Investment</a></li>
</ul>
<span id='reminder-text'>You can also click on ID to copy to clipboard</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="{% static '/js/downloadTemplate.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/js/idClickedScript.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you identify the view that handles the 'Export' button click, and copy that to point to a different view which calls your export?

Comment: they're both the same view.